# Query DynamoDB based on a Wildcard or a Regex Replacement

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to query Dynamo DB based on some serial numbers.  They are a bunch of different lengths and configurations. Based on the first 4 characters of the serial number I can determine if the device belongs to me or not.  If it doesn't I need to change a value in Dynamo to distinguish an invalid device.

Begins With works fine for finding valid cases, but I would need the anti-pattern for what I want.

For Example: Python Boto3

```
if not dynamodb:
    dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('Devices')

try:
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr("device").begins_with("1") |
                         Attr("device").begins_with("ABC1") |
                         Attr("device").begins_with("ABC 1")
    )
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    return response["Items"]
```

The above returns the opposite of what I need. I am open to any kind of solution in Python, Node, TypeScript, Java, C#.

Comment: Those filters are always in the beginning.

Comment: Not sure of the answer here but you can do client side filtering too. FilterExpression here ain't adding any benefit in terms of latency, RCUs

Comment: I am just establishing an example of what is trying to be done, thanks for the advice.